# Highstock, error: Uncaught TypeError: w[(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)] is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to create a highstock chart, but am getting the following error:

> error: Uncaught TypeError: w[(intermediate value)(intermediate
>   value)(intermediate value)] is not a constructor

My JSON seems valid, and my javascript too, any idea howto fix this?

Javascript:

```
    $.getJSON('<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>analytic/weekly_views_json', function(data) 
    {
       // Create the chart
        $('#container2').highcharts('StockChart', {

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },

            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
                data: data,
                type: 'spline',

            }]
        });
    });
```

Json:

```
[[1420547368,1],[1423225768,1],[1425644968,1],[1428319768,1],[1430911768,1],[1433590168,1],[1452083368,1],[1454761768,1],[1457267368,1],[1458131368,1],[1459942168,1],[1494070168,1]]
```

Comment: The timestamps look like a UNIX format, but should be multiplied by 1000 to achieve JS format. Have you a live demo of your chart, because your code is correct.

Comment: The code you have provided seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/o079d5s6/2/ Could you create a fiddle demonstrating the issue?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I exactly use highchart example but I have got above error! [jsfiddle highchart example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/)

Comment: @randommman Could you find the solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First solution:**

I had same error, i used `highchart` as below in my `HTML` code:

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
...
</head>
```

and my `js` code was:

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
...
});
```

with respect to [`highchart documention`](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#highstock-features-in-highcharts), we must use `Highcharts.Chart` to create new `highstock`.
so i changed my code to:

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
...
</head>
```

and my `js` code was:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            },
...
});
```

and this error has been resolved!

**Second solution:**

also with respect to [this documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/16),  if you are running Chart and StockChart in combination, you only need to load the highstock.js file.

so changed my code to:

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
...
</head>
```

and my `js` code was:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            },
...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
<script src="../lib/highcharts.js"/>
<script src="../lib/highcharts-more.js"/>

 var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'Temperature'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'HighStock'
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['1','2','3','4'],
                        title: {
                            text: 'day'
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'values'
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'temperature',
                        data: [
                            [5,30],[10,35],[15,40],[20,45]
                        ],
                    }]
                });
```